# Does EKEvent strip linebreaks from its location field?

Tags: ios, calendar, newline, ekevent

In an app I am working on, we need to parse fields from `EKEvents` taken from the native calendar on iOS. Our company has its own calendar app provider service which we can synchronize on our iPhones & iPads.

For some reason, when creating a calendar event with our company's calendar service, we are allowed to put newlines in the `location` field, something that a few employees rely on.

The issue is that when retrieving the `EKEvents` for parsing, we find that the `location` field's newline was replaced by a simple space, which kinda breaks our regular expressions.

**ics Location text**

```
0700 4646056 \n2333025#
```

**EKEvent Location text**

```
0700 4646056  2333025#
```

So the question is: Is the iOS Calendar applying any kind of formatting to the event fields ? If it is the case, is there anything we can do to prevent that ?